# Sticky header for wordpress changes size and logo size as I scroll down

Tags: themes, headers

I am using [Themify](https://themify.me/) to construct my website.

I have a parallax site partially constructed, however when I scroll down my logo and header changes size. It is a sticky header and goes from being transparent to a color. Where can I find the options to change this in the themify builder? I just want to keep the size consistent as I scroll down.

Here is the site: http://willwiseman.us

Answer (score 0):

you can modify style in custom css code in theme options or install plugin custom css or modify the main css files

1.- for logo size in sticky header add this code in custom css or modify file in 
`/wp-content/themes/themify-ultra/styles/header-horizontal.css` line#21 change height to 60px from 30px

```
.fixed-header-on #site-logo img {
  height: 60px;
  width: auto;
  transition: all .3s;
}
```

2.- for sticky header background color add the below code in custom css or modify in:

```
.transparent-header #headerwrap.fixed-header {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```